# Rule Engine in Domain Driver Design ( rate limiter as an example)

Tags: akka, domain-driven-design

What is a good way to integrate rule engines into a Domain Driver Design? 
For an example: If I have a generic rate limiting service, that has

- Resources( ads, machines, etc.), with attributes ("category", "owner", etc)
- Events (ad view, ad click, etc.). Each event has an associated user and resource (User X acted on Event Y)
- Limits: For example "at most 5 entertainment ads a day", or "show ad X at most 2 times an hour"
  The domain is richer than that, but this should be enough for the example.

It seems like there are 3 aggregates: Resource, Event, Limit. However, evaluating the limits for a user requires collecting all the (a)events performed by the user, (b) all resources, (c) all limits, and then evaluating the rules. So this 'Rule Engine' component needs to maintain knowledge about all the aggregates.

One way to design it would be to have a rule engine "Saga" per request/user, that collects all the information from the aggregates and evaluates the rules. Can somebody suggest another design?

p.s
I am using Akka, so the above design lends itself nicely to an actor-per-request.

Comment: I'm not sure Aggregates (or DDD tactical patterns in general) are the right lens to look through for a rules engine bounded context. Aggregates and Sagas imply that you have more or less complex or long running business transactions to carry out and state transition invariants to enforce. *"Collecting information"*, *"maintaining knowledge"*, *"evaluating rules"* in order to determine if you'll display an ad looks like a whole other animal.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is to keep your "rules engine" ignorant of any specific aggregates and rather keep it all data related.

You could pass the required "arguments" to the rules engine to evaluate a given "expression" or "method" of sorts.  For example:

Method: "Rate Limiter"
Arguments:

- "AdClickCount": 10
- "Category": "socks"
- etc.

The rules engine would would the data to come back with the required response.

Those are the broad strokes.  I implemented something similar for an insurance company to determine premiums based on the many rules associated with the various products.

I am working on an open-source version but I don't get nearly enough time to finish but perhaps there are some ideas there: https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Abacus

Comment: I like the idea. But you would still need something to collect all the data and parse it to a langauge the rule engine can understand

Comment: That's correct.  This isn't really something that is going to fit into your core domain (it is a domain in and of itself - generic sub-domain if you will).  But yes, you'd have to interface with it on some level.  You *may* call out of your core domain but I'm more inclined to pass in results that the core domain would just use.  Testing is more state-based then.  Anyway, just an option :)

Answer (score 0):

*Supposing that you have an Application and it needs to be rate-limited:*

Rate-limiting should be view as another Bounded context. It could have two sides:

- the administration part, where the resources and rules are added, edited and deleted and
- the verification part, where the actions are accepted (and their *counter* incremented) or rejected; for both you can include explanatory messages, i.e. `RetryAfter: 10 seconds` or `Remaining: 99`.

Verifying the limits depends on your architecture. For example, if you use an API Gateway and microservices, then for each action (`ad view`, `ad click`) that API Gateway checks the request against the Rate-limiting microservice.

P.S. I can't give you a general answer, it depends on each use-case.

Comment: That's the high level architecture.... which is exactly the way we have it now. I am asking about the design inside the rate limiting bounded context

Comment: @EugeneMi low level, the administration part seems CRUD. The verification part is also CRUD with some possible Domain services.